# How do you make filesystems in mac OSX

Tags: osx, mkfs

How do you make filesystems in OSX? Mac OSX doesn't have the `mkfs` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On BSD-derived Unix systems, newfs is more commonly used than mkfs.

Under Mac OS X, you would use newfs_*type* as the command, where *type* is one of *hfs*, *msdos*, *exfat* or *udf*.  There are man pages for all of these.  As the other answer mentions, you can use diskutil to create filestems but by using the newfs variants you can set specific filesystem parameters unavailable via diskutil.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Disk Utility (`diskutil` from command-line).

For example:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ VolumeName /dev/disk2
```

Refer to the [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html).